# animated search form inside blue bar in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, search

I have a screenshot as shown below which I have to replicate in HTML/CSS..

[image]

I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98xqsbrL/3/embedded/result/) for the above screen-shot **(still some work left to be done)**. The snippets of HTML and CSS codes which I have used in order to make the fiddle is:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav-top-searchbar">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="search">
        <span class=" fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true "></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav-top-searchbar {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #244A64;
    padding: 1%;
}

.searchicon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
    padding: 6px;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #244A64;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

**(1)** I am wondering what changes do I need to make in the above CSS codes so that if I **hit** on the surrounded **white square border (marked with arrow in the screenshot) across the search-icon**, it should expand in a way similar to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_anim_search).

After the **surrounding square border expands across the search-icon**, we can do manual search.

The **expansion** of the **solid white square border** should cover **50% of the blue bar**.

**(2)** Also, in my fiddle, **I want to remove the outer most surrounded white square border**.

**Note:**

The surrounding white square border across the search icon should be always present **inside the dark blue bar**.

Comment: You will need some js for your first problem

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Added as a tag

Comment: Do you want the search box to expand on clicking the icon?

Comment: @FridayAmeh  Yes, I want to expand the search box on clicking the icon.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
     .nav-top-searchbar {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #244A64;
        padding: 1%;
    }
    
    .searchicon {
        position: absolute;
        left: 25px;
        top: 25px;
        border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 3.5px;
        padding: 6px;
    }
    
    
    
    input[type=text] {
        width: 130px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #244A64;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-position: 10px 10px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    input[type=text]:focus {
        width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="nav-top-searchbar">
        <form>
            <input id="sc1" type="text" name="search">
            <span id="sc" class=" fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true "></span>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("sc1").onfocus = function(){
  document.getElementById("sc").style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("sc").onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("sc1").style.width = "50%";
 this.style.display = "none";
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It perfectly makes sense. I am wondering if you can update it in the fiddle.

Comment: I have put your code in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98xqsbrL/20/embedded/result/).

Comment: There are still some minor changes. If you read my 2nd point in the problem statement, I don't want the outer most square border.  I only want the inner most square border and if I click on my inner most square border, it should expand .

Comment: Ok You mean you want only the inner icon then when click on it, the search input should display...

Comment: I tried removing the outer-most square border through CSS but somehow it didn't work. I just want only inner-most square border.

Comment: And the innermost square border should expand, when I hit on the search-icon.

Comment: The expansion should take in way similar to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_anim_search) inside the blue bar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169006/discussion-between-friday-ameh-and-user5447339).